# how to disable minor mode (enabled using prog-mode-hook) for a particular major mode

Tags: hooks, minor-mode

I've enabled auto-complete-mode mode using prog-mode-hook like so: `(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'auto-complete-mode)`, but I want auto-complete-mode to be disabled for python-mode. How can I achieve this ?

I tried doing this :- 
`(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda() (auto-complete-mode -1)))`
But, auto-complete-mode is still enabled for python-mode.

Comment: Can you update the question with the exact code you used related to `prog-mode-hook` and `MAJOR-MODE-hook`? Note about your dummy form above.. it should be "major-mode-hook", not "major-mode".

Comment: edited the post with actual code used.

Comment: Try customizing the `ac-modes` variable.. I haven't tried but you probably just need to remove `python-mode` from that list.

Comment: The code shown in your edited question works just fine. You must be doing something else. Check that you're not running `global-auto-complete-mode` for starters.

Comment: @KaushalModi tried removing python-mode from ac-modes variable, still auto-complete mode is enabled by default in python-mode. 

@phils I haven't enabled `global-auto-complete-mode`

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan The best way is (you probably already know it) to comment out your whole config and gradually uncomment it in halves till you narrow down to the problematic part. Before you do that, you can also grep your config + installed packages for 'auto-complete' and see what comes up.. probably it got enabled globally by customize?

Comment: I removed the `(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'auto-complete-mode)` line and enabled `global-auto-complete-mode`, reloaded .emacs and auto-complete-mode is not enabled by default in python-mode anymore. 
So, the problem was enabling auto-complete-mode with prog-mode-hook. 

ehh so, should I avoid using prog-mode-hooks to enable minor modes from now on ? I never thought using it could cause such issues x.x

Comment: Please, someone create an answer and, please, Chakravarthy Raghunandan accept this answer then. Doing that marks this question as solved in the overview.

Comment: I did `emacs -Q -L popup-el -L auto-complete -l auto-complete.el` evaluated `(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'auto-complete-mode)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda() (auto-complete-mode -1)))` then did `M-x python-mode` and auto-complete was not enabled. So this works fine, you have something in your .emacs that is messing things up.

Comment: I'm not sure what I have in my .emacs that could have caused the problem. I don't have anything else related to auto-complete that could mess it up. Changing to global-auto-complete-mode solved the problem though.

Comment: I have a similar question with https://github.com/jordonbiondo/column-enforce-mode/ I have globally enabled but want it to be disabled for C++ or thanks to directory local variables...

Comment: Here is a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837511/automatically-disable-a-global-minor-mode-for-a-specific-major-mode

Comment: @YvesMartin it's been so long that I forgot I had a solution for this problem. You don't need to use `.dir-locals.el` for that purpose, If using lambdas did not work, you can do something like [this](https://github.com/CSRaghunandan/.emacs.d/blob/f5c5f384fcb3038e117ea7e1d8d4dcd42b974393/setup-files/setup-highlight.el#L28)

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan So please publish your answer as code snippet here. Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done very easily with hooks for major-modes like so:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda ()
                              (highlight-indent-guides-mode -1)))
```

If for some reason this did not work, you could try something like this:

```
  (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook (lambda ()
                              (unless (eq major-mode 'python-mode)
                                (highlight-indent-guides-mode))))
```