# Disable auto-fill mode in all the major modes

Tags: minor-mode

When try to disable 'auto-fill-mode`, I search the following answers

[how to disable minor mode (enabled using prog-mode-hook) for a particular major mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26094/how-to-disable-minor-mode-enabled-using-prog-mode-hook-for-a-particular-major)

This answer narrow it focus on the python-mode

[word wrap - How can I disable auto-fill mode in emacs? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878623/how-can-i-disable-auto-fill-mode-in-emacs)

This answer provide various solutions.

```
(auto-fill-mode -1)
(remove-hook 'text-mode-hook #'turn-on-auto-fill)
```

What's the decent solution to disable a minor mode in version 26+

Comment: `auto-fill-mode` is a special case. The general question "What's the decent solution to disable a minor mode in version 26+" is a separate question. Normally, `auto-fill-mode` is globally disabled and you turn it on by [some methods](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Turning-on-auto_002dfill-by-default.html). So the answer would be to reverse the configuration that turns on `auto-fill-mode` in your setup.

Comment: Note that `auto-fill-mode` is a configuration option in `text-mode-hook`. Try to customize `text-mode-hook`.

Comment: If it's a general problem then you should find in your own config where you are *enabling* `auto-fill-mode` (or setting `auto-fill-function`), and then stop doing that.  If it's only enabled in a small number of situations, then give us more information about that.